# Como encontrar a interseção entre uma linha e uma função matemática?

Tags: c#, matemática, geometria

Estou com um problema onde preciso encontrar a interseção de duas funções matemáticas. Eu tenho a fórmula da primeira função e duas coordenadas, onde *ab* e *cd* são meus pontos. Para passar estas coordenadas para uma função, utilizo a [equação da linha por dois pontos](https://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/linear_equation/write-equation/equation-of-line-given-two-points.php), e é este meu problema.

A primeira função é representada por `f(x) = |x| - cos(3x)`, que crio este *desenho*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já que a fórmula já está pronta, eu escrevi ela em C# com:

```
static Vector2 CossineFormula(int x)
{
     double y = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Math.Abs(x), 2)) - Math.Cos(x * 3);
     return new Vector2(x, y);
}
```

Até aí OK. Agora, tenho dois pontos que citei, e eu não consigo prosseguir com a equação de linha de dois pontos porquê não posso definir uma função de forma dinâmica, ou pelo menos não encontrei como.

A interseção é dada pela continuação dos pontos *ab* e *cd* até criar a interceptação *ef*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não consigo encontrar essa interseção porque não consigo passar os dois pontos para função matemática.

Tentei usar a fórmula da rampa (Slope) como está no tutorial acima mencionado, mas travei nesta parte (no tutorial é o Step 2):

```
static Vector2 CossineIntersection(Vector2 a, Vector2 b)
{
    double distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(b.X - a.X, 2) + Math.Pow(b.Y - a.Y, 2));
    double slope = (b.Y - a.Y) / (b.X - a.X);
    double intercept = (2 * slope); // onde continuo com b?
}
```

*Slope* foi calculado, mas nesta etapa:

> Substitute the slope for 'm' in the slope intercept form of the equation
>   `y = mx + b`

Passei para `y = (2 * slope)` mas não tive continuar *b*.

Eu também perguntei sobre como encontrar esta interseção no [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3372307/how-to-find-the-intersection-of-an-straight-line-and-a-function).

Todas as formas de fazer interseção, eu não consigo representar em programação. Eu sei que é possível, mas não encontro em nenhum lugar algo do tipo.

**Nota:** não é uma interseção entre duas linhas, e sim entre uma linha e uma função.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar o [método da bissecção](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_da_bisse%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Você basicamente está tentando achar a raiz dessa equação:

```
y = |x| - cos(3x) - (mx + b)
```

A raiz dessa equação é onde as suas duas linhas se encontram.

Como `Vector2` trabalha com `float`s, então vamos tratar todos os números como `float`s.

Primeiro, a função linear:

```
static float LinearFormula(float x, Vector2 a, Vector2 b)
{
     float slope = (b.Y - a.Y) / (b.X - a.X);
     float dx = x - a.X;
     float dy = slope * dx; 
     return dy + a.Y;
}
```

A sua função com o cosseno:

```
static float CossineFormula(float x)
{
     return Math.Abs(x) - (float) Math.Cos(x * 3);
}
```

Note que simplifiquei o `Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Math.Abs(x), 2))` para `Math.Abs(x)`. Não há porque elevar ao quadrado só para tirar a raiz quadrada depois, ainda mais que você já está aplicando o `Abs`.

Sua função:

```
static float MyFormula(float x, Vector2 a, Vector2 b)
{
     return CossineFormula(x) - LinearFormula(x, a, b);
}
```

E então, procuramos a raiz por bissecções consecutivas:

```
static Vector2 FindIntersection(Vector2 a, Vector2 b)
{
    float x1 = 2;
    float x2 = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        float d = (x2 + x1) / 2;
        if (d == x1 || d == x2) break;
        float v3 = MyFormula(d, a, b);
        if (v3 > 0)
        {
            x2 = d;
        }
        else
        {
            x1 = d;
        }
    }
    return new Vector2(x1, CossineFormula(x1));
}
```

Nessa função, 2 e 3 são os valores iniciais do intervalo onde procuraremos a raiz da função. A escolha desses valores é arbitrária, mas eu fiz sabendo que (a) para 2 temos um valor negativo, (b) para 3 um positivo e (c) neste intervalo só existe uma única raiz para a função. Logo, dividindo esse intervalo em partes cada vez menores, podemos achar onde está a raiz.

O `for` deve rodar o número de vezes o suficiente para encontrar a raiz, e poderia até ser um `while (true)`. Mas coloquei um contador para dar um limite máximo no número de iterações, caso algo dê errado.

Por fim, para testar:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(FindIntersection(new Vector2(0, 4), new Vector2(1, 3)));
}
```

O resultado é esse:

```
<2.354912, 1.645088>
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](http://ideone.com/zKnx83)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Fiz o teste no teu código utilizando os pontos `0, 4` e `1, 3` e a interseção deu `X = 3,033` e `Y = 3.051`. Nesta [calculadora de funções](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), estes mesmos pontos dão uma interseção de aproximadamente `X = 2.35` e `Y = 1.66`. O que está errado?

Comment: @CypherPotato Corrigido. Desculpe, eu havia feito uma confusão inicialmente.

Comment: Victor, acho que você se confundiu na condição para definir a bisseção. Não basta verificar o sinal de `d`, que é o ponto médio, mas sim compará-lo aos valores de `v1` e `v2` atuais. Neste exemplo, você atualizou `v1` quando `d > 0`. Isso funcionaria se a curva fosse crescente, mas é decrescente. Se `d > 0` você precisará atualizar o ponto que também é positivo, seja ele `v1` ou `v2`.

Comment: Considerando o comentário acima, acho que só funcionou por "sorte" por a curva ser decrescente e você atualizar `v2` quando `v3 > 0`. Essa mesma condição não funcionará se a curva for crescente (ou estou enganado?).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Ela se baseia no fato de que o `x1` sempre produz um `v1` negativo e que o `x2` sempre produz um `v2` positivo. Isso não é algo lá muito geral, mas para tornar isso em algo mais geral, eu teria também que abarcar escolha do `x1` e do `x2` inicial e parametrizar a função a ser bisseccionada, o que deixaria um pouco mais complicado do que o autor da pergunta necessita.

Comment: Ah, verdade, existe essa premissa xD Eu já estava pensando em algo para quando fosse `v1` positivo e `v2` negativo também haha